# Add a "share to LinkedIn" link

Tags: feature-request

Seems there are share to facebook, twitter,google+,but no share to linkedin.

Can add a feature 'share to linkedin'

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116730/why-cant-we-share-on-linkedin-anymore

Comment: LinkedIn is a festering blister, a spammy evil empire. I like that it doesn't have an icon here.

Comment: @Pekka웃 have you noticed how shallow a lot of promoted articles are on LinkedIn? It's very disappointing for a "professional networking" site.

Comment: These comments are old. but now we need this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309151/add-badge-to-linkedin-profile

Answer (score 4):

From [Why can't we share on LinkedIn anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116732/163250):

> As [Jeff answered here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94802/135201) those links were experimental. The LinkedIn one simply wasn't being used, not to nearly the volume of the others...so we removed the extra clutter from the UI.
>
> It will likely be replaced with Google+, given they ever provide an officially supported link-only way to share.