# Add badge to LinkedIn profile

Tags: feature-request, reputation

So, [Code School](https://codeschool.reamaze.com/kb/general/how-do-i-add-a-badge-to-my-linkedin-profile), Pluralsight, Microsoft Virtual Academy, and many other websites alike offer **"Add badge to my LinkedIn profile"** features on their websites. I believe that enabling us to display our Stack Overflow achievements on our LinkedIn profiles would be really valuable.

I have found some [3-year-old posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121355/how-can-i-insert-my-stack-overflow-rating-into-linkedin) on this matter, but none of their answers offers a satisfactory solution.

The most popular solution seems to be adding SO's flair to the summary, but the generated image gets highly distorted once LinkedIn turns SO's `png` into a `jpg`. Also, imported flairs turn into modal openers instead of something actually useful, like a link to a user's profile.

Shouldn't we have such a feature?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253809/add-a-share-to-linkedin-link?rq=1#comment15746_253809

Comment: It's funny that 1 year ago nobody was interested in this (take a look at [the linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253809/add-a-share-to-linkedin-link?rq=1#comment15746_253809)), but now this is an extremely popular request!

Comment: No offence, I am in no opposition but once this is implemented, the users may be intended to post Q&A to improvise their own Linkedin profile rather than focusing on improvement/helping the OPs. This is just my thinking, it may be wrong and may have other interpretations too.

Comment: @sharvil111 I think of that as an added bonus. It will only increase the knowledge base we have on SO and improve it (with more contributors). What's the harm in offering some sort of an incentive or motivation to increase contribution to the community? This will attract more of us to start contributing to the community (who today do not care to give back). Eventually there will be a mutual benefit.

Comment: Not sure they'd want a way of cross promoting another _job-esque_ site when they are making their own push in the jobs market.

Answer (score 30):

I have suggest like this, I add my Stack Overflow profile in the Volunteer Experience secession in the Linked in. I believe it make sense. So I added it as following.

- Organization : Stack Overflow
- Role : Individual Contributor
- Cause :Education
- Description : add your stack overflow profile link

Comment: Fits perfectly in the Volunteer Experience section.

Comment: A person cannot tab on description and also cannot copy and paste our profile link from here

Comment: @SAURABH I add my profile link in the description. Yes, it does not work as a link, but if the viewer is curious to check the profile, they can easily copy and paste the link and visit the profile.

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to LinkedIn and log in to your account
2. Go to Edit Profile by hovering over the Profile tab in the top left
3. Choose which section of your profile you want to display badges in (for example, the summary section at the top of your profile)
4. Hover over the + dropdown and click Add Link
5. Log in to your Open Badges Backpack and open the badge collection you want to display
6. Click the Share This Group icon in the collection box and choose a social media platform to access the URL for your badge collection
7. Copy the link for this page (you do not have to go through with sharing your badges if you don’t want to, just close the pop-up window after copying the link)
8. Paste the link into the Add Link field in LinkedIn, add descriptor info, and save

Comment: I don't see a diamond next to your name. Is this an officially recognized way of adding Stack Overflow flair to LinkedIn?

Comment: Adding the link to flair in Linkedin profile displays a stretched and distorted image. Any way to make the image display properly?

Comment: Seems like this answer isn't relevant in today's LinkedIn profile pages, or I've missed something?

Comment: i thought i was the only one seeing this, cant see the add badge button, i've been looking for it.

Answer (score 10):

It seems @AndrewEmad 's answer is no longer helpful as Linkedin might have removed step 5. But the below solution worked for me.

1. Make sure to take a screenshot (I used *Lightshot* app - *Mac/Windows*) of your SO badge/reputation which you want to upload to your Linkedin.
2. Go to your Linkedin profile.
3. Click on **Add Profile Section** Button (Next to your Avatar) > **Featured** Tab > **Media**.
4. Select your SO image which you created in step 1.
5. Add **Title**: StackOverflow and **Description**: [your profile link] and/or description.

And you are good to go!

Comment: As of Sep 2020, this answer is the more correct approach to add flair to one's LinkedIn account.

Comment: Agreed. That can probably only happen if LinkedIn collaborates with SO.